# Как сделать, если запрос завершился неудачей - отправить данные об ошибке администратору?

Tags: javascript

Задание:
Давайте напишем функцию, которая будет увеличивать зарплату сотруднику с наименьшей зарплатой.

Вам нужно

- Получает данные по всем работникам
- Находит работника с наименьшей    зарплатой
- Отправляет запрос на повышение зарплаты этому сотруднику на    20%
- Если запрос прошел успешно - отправить сотруднику уведомление об
  увеличении ЗП тектом: Hello, <имя>! Congratulations, your new salary
  is <новая ЗП>!
- Если запрос завершился неудачей - отправить данные об    ошибке
  администратору

Должна всегда возвращать resolved промис с boolean значением:

- true если увеличение прошло успешно
- false если нет

Все функции для получения/изменения данных асинхронны и возвращают промисы.
Вам предоставлены функции:

```
api.getEmployees(); // Возвращает массив с объектами {id: 343, name: 'Alex', salary: 20000}
api.setEmployeeSalary(employeeId, newSalary); // Принимает id сотрудника и новую зарплату. Возвращает новые данные по сотруднику.
api.notifyEmployee(employeeId, text); // Принимает id сотрудника и текст уведомления
api.notifyAdmin(error); // Принимает ошибку
```

Мой код

```
function increaseSalary() {
try {
    return api.getEmployees()
        .then(emp => {
            const [minSalaryEmployee] = emp.reduce(([minEmployee, minSalary], employee) => {
                const {salary} = employee;
                return (salary < minSalary
                    ? [employee, salary]
                    : [minEmployee, minSalary]
                );
            }, [null, Infinity]);
           
            const {id, salary: oldSalary} = minSalaryEmployee;
            const newSalary = oldSalary * 1.2;
            return {id, salary: newSalary};
        })
        .then(({id, salary}) => api.setEmployeeSalary(id, salary))
           .then(({name, id, salary}) => api.notifyEmployee(id, `Hello, ${name}! Congratulations, your new salary is ${salary}!`))
}catch(e){
  api.getEmployees().then(api.notifyAdmin(e))// не знаю как правильно сделать
}}


const api = {
  _employees: [
    { id: 1, name: 'Alex', salary: 120000 },
    { id: 2, name: 'Fred', salary: 110000 },
    { id: 3, name: 'Bob', salary: 80000 },
  ],

  getEmployees() {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
      resolve(this._employees.slice());
    });
  },

  setEmployeeSalary(employeeId, newSalary) {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
      this._employees = this._employees.map((employee) =>
        employee.id !== employeeId
          ? employee
          : {
            ...employee,
            salary: newSalary,
          }
      );
      resolve(this._employees.find(({ id }) => id === employeeId));
    });
  },

  notifyEmployee(employeeId, text) {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
      resolve(true);
    });
  },

  notifyAdmin(error) {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
      resolve(true);
    });
  },

  setEmployees(newEmployees) {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
      this._employees = newEmployees;
      resolve();
    });
  },
};
```

Comment: Вы забыли уточнить, с какой проблемой столкнулись

Comment: С пунктом "Если запрос завершился неудачей - отправить данные об ошибке администратору"